# Temporarily override locale with a context manager

Tags: python, locale

Is there a way to temporarily activate a locale within the scope of a block of code? Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'nl_BE.utf8')
```

Like this:

```
with override_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'nl_BE.utf8'):
   # Stuff here
```

That way I can also avoid any thread safety issues that may arise when using `setlocale`. My use case is parsing an uploaded file where the decimals use a comma instead of a period as the decimal separator (e.g. 1,25 instead of 1.25).

Comment: Are you writing a new program or do you have to respect existing code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that [Babel](https://pypi.org/project/Babel/) better fits my use case:

```
>>> parse_decimal('1,25', locale='nl_BE.utf8')
Decimal('1.25')
```

This approach is useful whenever I need to parse a Dutch decimal and doesn't require overriding any locales at all.

Comment: That was why i was asking if you are about to write a new program - if so, i would have suggested to go with Babel. Otherwise, working with the inhereintly non-thread safe `locale` of Python will be a mess

Comment: Sorry, I think I overlooked your comment at the top. I have enough freedom in this codebase to ditch `locale` if that's not what I need, so that'd work for me. Thanks for reaffirming my findings though. This gives me more confidence that Babel is a good solution here!

Answer (score 4):

You can write an easy and straight-forward contextmanager for this:

```
from locale import getlocale, setlocale
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def override_locale(category, locale_string):
    prev_locale_string = getlocale(category)
    setlocale(category, locale_string)
    yield
    setlocale(category, prev_locale_string)
```

Comment: Ah, i only did read now that what you are looking for is thread-safety... Let me check

Comment: This fails when `category == locale.LC_ALL`.

Comment: For me, getlocale returns wrong value for previous locale sometimes, locale.setlocale without second argument works better as in Serge Ballesta's answer

Answer (score 4):

Unsure whether you really want to do that. The locale may be global(*) to the program, so it could give a weird behaviour in a multithreaded context. Worse, the standard library documentation says:

> The C standard defines the locale as a program-wide property that may be relatively expensive to change. On top of that, some implementation are broken in such a way that frequent locale changes may cause core dumps.

That being said, it is possible to build a custom context manager:

```
class LocaleManager:
    def __init__(self, localename):
        self.name = localename
    def __enter__(self):
        self.orig = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE)
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, self.name)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, self.orig)
```

Example on a French Windows:

```
>>> print(locale.getlocale())
('fr_FR', 'cp1252')
>>> with LocaleManager("C"):
    print(locale.getlocale())


(None, None)
>>> print(locale.getlocale())
('fr_FR', 'cp1252')
```

Comment: Oof, that is definitely tricky. Looks like Babel will be a better approach in my case, but thank you for looking into this!