# Custom locale configuration for float conversion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point, locale

I need to convert a string in the format `"1.234.345,00"` to the `float` value `1234345.00`.

One way is to use repeated `str.replace`:

```
x = "1.234.345,00"
res = float(x.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))

print(res, type(res))
1234345.0 <class 'float'>
```

However, this appears manual and non-generalised. This [heavily upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/9209546) suggests using the `locale` library. But my default locale doesn't have the same conventions as my input string. I then discovered a way to extract the characters used in local conventions as a dictionary:

```
import locale

print(locale.localeconv())

{'int_curr_symbol': '', 'currency_symbol': '', 'mon_decimal_point': '',
 ..., 'decimal_point': '.', 'thousands_sep': '', 'grouping': []}
```

Is there a way to update this dictionary, save as a custom locale and then be able to call this custom locale going forwards. Something like:

```
mylocale = locale.create_new_locale()  # "blank" conventions or copied from default
mylocale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'] = '.'
mylocale.localeconv()['decimal_point'] = ','

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, mylocale)
atof('123.456,78')  # 123456.78
```

If this isn't possible, how do we get a list of all available locale and their conventions? Seems anti-pattern to "deduce" the correct configuration from the conventions (not to mention inefficient / manual), so I was hoping for a generic solution such as above pseudo-code.

---

**Edit:** Here's my attempt at finding all locales where `thousands_sep == '.'` and `decimal_point == ','`. In fact, more generally, to group locales by combinations of these parameters:

```
import locale
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for alias in locale.locale_alias:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, alias)
    env = locale.localeconv()
    d[(env['thousands_sep'], env['decimal_point'])].append(alias)
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-f8f6a6db7637> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for alias in locale.locale_alias:
----> 7     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, alias)
      8     env = locale.localeconv()
      9     d[(env['thousands_sep'], env['decimal_point'])].append(alias)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\locale.py in setlocale(category, locale)
    596         # convert to string
    597         locale = normalize(_build_localename(locale))
--> 598     return _setlocale(category, locale)
    599 
    600 def resetlocale(category=LC_ALL):

Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: Not python specific, but [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21316/how-can-i-customize-a-system-locale) if something I've used in the past to create a custom locale, and I've been able to use it within Python after setting everything up.

Comment: @user3483203, Sounds interesting, I'll have a look. But I was hoping for a solution which is easily transportable. Of course, the answer may be it's *not* possible. In which case, one viable way is to "choose" the right locale.. if you can find one that "fits".

Comment: is this relevant ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737783/temporarily-override-locale-with-a-context-manager

Comment: @JLPeyret, It *might* be useful. The only part I'd struggle with is finding the "right" locale for the conventions I want. Or modifying them to align with what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709026/how-can-i-list-all-available-windows-locales-in-python-console

Comment: how about going through the list till you had get what you want?  how do you know which seps and decimal signs you need from an arriving string?  in advance?  could you set up a precomputed dict? { (‘.’,’,’) : ‘en_uk’...}

Comment: @JLPeyret, This exactly what I'm trying, e.g. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, list(locale.locale_alias.keys())[0])` but errors with `Error: unsupported locale setting`.

Comment: can you add a list of sample data?  [(input, expectation),...]?   that would make it easier to reason about. and add any otherwise known facts, if any. like max decimal precision.  now keep in mind you might need to distinguish 123.346 the 123+0.346 from 123.346 the 123346

Comment: @JLPeyret, Sure, see my updated question.

Comment: Is "1.234.345,00" the **only** format needing processing?  Otherwise I'd need samples in order to investigate further.

Comment: I've also needed to use "1,234,345.00". I would expect there are locale(s) for each. I was hoping (see my question edit) to iterate all available locales and create a dictionary, e.g. `d[(',','.')] = ['de_de', 'us-dasf', etc], d[('.', ',')] = ['some_other_locale', ...]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pop open the source code for locale, you can see that there is a variable called `_override_localeconv` (which seems to be for testing purposes).

```python
# With this dict, you can override some items of localeconv's return value.
# This is useful for testing purposes.
_override_localeconv = {}
```

Trying the following does seem to override the dictionary without changing the entire locale, though it probably has some unintended consequences, especially since changing locales isn't threadsafe. Be careful!

```python
import locale

locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = "."
locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"] = ","

print locale.atof('123.456,78')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRCEnPzkxJ5WLC0LrxeeXpRYVZaakxkMEkvPzyqKVgFpKixPzUorji1MLlGIVbBWU9JTwa0lJTc7MTcyJL8jPzCuBaNFR4uIqKAJyoZbqJZbkp2moGxoZ65mYmumYW6hr/v8PAA)

Comment: This is excellent! I will have a look at the source in a little more detail. Seems like we aren't *meant* to use it. But for a simple task like this I'm hoping there *aren't* any issues.

Comment: @jpp if you look at the source of locale the atof function as actually doing exactly what your origional example code is doing with string replacements

Comment: @JamesKent, Noted. Though it's worth pointing out there may be aesthetic reasons (stylistic, code maintenance, etc) why one might prefer to use `atof` instead of explicit `str.replace`.

Comment: I understand that, changing the locale may affect the function of libraries being used elsewhere in your project, but putting a function into your own project to do this without changing the locale you can avoid unintended side effects. My comment was more to note that thats how it's done behind the scenes anyway

Comment: +1 @JamesKent this can have very bad side effects in your code. Do not use on a production web server for example, use Babel instead

Comment: But `grouping` doesn't work on my German Windows without setting the locale. `locale.format_string('%f', 123456.78, grouping=True)` results in `'123456,780000'`. There is a key `grouping` in the dictionary. But I'm not sure how to use it or if it is even relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something, using Babel, that works for me.

First you feed it some test data, with your expectations and it builds a dictionary of separator to locale alias that fits.

Then you can convert from that point on.

```
import string
from decimal import Decimal
from babel.numbers import parse_decimal, NumberFormatError
from babel.core import UnknownLocaleError
import locale

traindata = [
    ("1.234.345,00", Decimal("1234345.00")),
    ("1,234,345.00", Decimal("1234345.00")),
    ("345", Decimal("345.00")),
]

data = traindata + [
    ("345,00", Decimal("345.00")),
    ("345.00", Decimal("345.00")),
    ("746", Decimal("746.00")),
]

def findseps(input_):
    #you need to have no separator 
    #or at least a decimal separator for this to work...

    seps = [c for c in input_ if not c in string.digits]
    if not seps:
        return ""

    sep = seps[-1]
    #if the decimal is something then thousand will be the other...
    seps = "." + sep if sep == "," else "," + sep
    return seps 


def setup(input_, exp, lookup):


    key = findseps(input_)

    if key in lookup:
        return

    for alias in locale.locale_alias:
        #print(alias)

        try:
            got = parse_decimal(input_, locale=alias)
        except (NumberFormatError,UnknownLocaleError, ValueError) as e:
            continue
        except (Exception,) as e:
            raise
        if exp == got:
            lookup[key] = alias
            return


def convert(input_, lookup):
    seps = findseps(input_)
    try:
        locale_ = lookup[seps]
        convert.locale_ = locale_
    except (KeyError,) as e:
        convert.locale_ = None
        return "unexpected seps:%s" % seps

    try:
        return parse_decimal(input_, locale=locale_)
    except (Exception,) as e:
        return e


lookup = {}

#train your data
for input_, exp in traindata:
    setup(input_, exp, lookup)

#once it's trained you know which locales to use
print(data)


for input_, exp in data:
    got = convert(input_, lookup)

    # print (input_)
    msg = "%s => %s with local:%s:" % (input_, got, convert.locale_)
    if exp == got:
        print("\n  success : " + msg)
    else:
        print("\n  failure : " + msg)

print(lookup)
```

output:

```
[('1.234.345,00', Decimal('1234345.00')), ('1,234,345.00', Decimal('1234345.00')), ('345', Decimal('345.00')), ('345,00', Decimal('345.00')), ('345.00', Decimal('345.00')), ('746', Decimal('746.00'))]

  success : 1.234.345,00 => 1234345.00 with local:is_is:

  success : 1,234,345.00 => 1234345.00 with local:ko_kr.euc:

  success : 345 => 345 with local:ko_kr.euc:

  success : 345,00 => 345.00 with local:is_is:

  success : 345.00 => 345.00 with local:ko_kr.euc:

  success : 746 => 746 with local:ko_kr.euc:
{',.': 'ko_kr.euc', '': 'ko_kr.euc', '.,': 'is_is'}
```

Comment: Very neat, will definitely come in handy! I'll need to read up a bit on `babel` (a library entirely new to me). But this does what I was looking for initially.

Comment: If you use ko_kr.euc it gives an error: parse_decimal('1.234.345,00', locale='ko_kr.euc')
NumberFormatError: '1.234.345,00' is not a valid decimal number

Comment: which is why you trap all the alias exceptions to only use that work....

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts in your question:

1. How can I parse '1.234.345,00' in a generic way?
2. How can I easily find the locale associated to '1.234.345,00'?

You can use the amazing [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) library for both.

### How can I parse '1.234.345,00' in a generic way?

One locale associated with a `.` thousands separator and a `,` decimal separator is `ger_de`, for German.

To parse it, simply use

```
>>> from babel.numbers import parse_decimal
>>> parse_decimal('1.234.345,00', locale='ger_de')
Decimal('1234345.00')
```

### How can I easily find the locale associated to '1.234.345,00'?

Use this routine which checks the string to parse against the expected value for all locales, and returns the ones that are compatible:

```
import locale
from babel.numbers import parse_decimal
from decimal import Decimal

def get_compatible_locales(string_to_parse, expected_decimal):
    compatible_aliases = []
    for alias in locale.locale_alias:
        try:
            parsed_decimal = parse_decimal(string_to_parse, locale=alias)
            if parsed_decimal == expected_decimal:
                compatible_aliases.append(alias)
        except Exception:
            continue
    return compatible_aliases
```

For your example:

```
>>> print(get_compatible_locales('1.234.345,00', Decimal('1234345')))
['ar_dz', 'ar_lb', 'ar_ly', 'ar_ma', 'ar_tn', 'ast_es', 'az', 'az_az', 'az_az.iso88599e', 'bs', 'bs_ba', 'ca', 'ca_ad', 'ca_es', 'ca_es@valencia', 'ca_fr', 'ca_it', 'da', 'da_dk', 'de', 'de_at', 'de_be', 'de_de', 'de_lu', 'el', 'el_cy', 'el_gr', 'el_gr@euro', 'en_be', 'en_dk', 'es', 'es_ar', 'es_bo', 'es_cl', 'es_co', 'es_ec', 'es_es', 'es_py', 'es_uy', 'es_ve', 'eu', 'eu_es', 'fo', 'fo_fo', 'fr_lu', 'fy_nl', 'ger_de', 'gl', 'gl_es', 'hr', 'hr_hr', 'hsb_de', 'id', 'id_id', 'in', 'in_id', 'is', 'is_is', 'it', 'it_it', 'kl', 'kl_gl', 'km_kh', 'lb_lu', 'lo', 'lo_la', 'lo_la.cp1133', 'lo_la.ibmcp1133', 'lo_la.mulelao1', 'mk', 'mk_mk', 'nl', 'nl_aw', 'nl_be', 'nl_nl', 'ps_af', 'pt', 'pt_br', 'ro', 'ro_ro', 'rw', 'rw_rw', 'sl', 'sl_si', 'sr', 'sr@cyrillic', 'sr@latn', 'sr_cs', 'sr_cs.iso88592@latn', 'sr_cs@latn', 'sr_me', 'sr_rs', 'sr_rs@latn', 'sr_yu', 'sr_yu.cp1251@cyrillic', 'sr_yu.iso88592', 'sr_yu.iso88595', 'sr_yu.iso88595@cyrillic', 'sr_yu.microsoftcp1251@cyrillic', 'sr_yu.utf8', 'sr_yu.utf8@cyrillic', 'sr_yu@cyrillic', 'tr', 'tr_cy', 'tr_tr', 'vi', 'vi_vn', 'vi_vn.tcvn', 'vi_vn.tcvn5712', 'vi_vn.viscii', 'vi_vn.viscii111', 'wo_sn']
```

### Bonus: How can I have a human-readable version of these locales?

Use the following routine, where `my_locale` should be your own locale:

```
from babel import Locale

def get_display_name(alias, my_locale='en_US'):
    l = Locale.parse(alias)
    return l.get_display_name(my_locale)
```

You can then use it this way:

```
>>> print({loc: get_display_name(loc) for loc in locales})
{'ar_dz': 'Arabic (Algeria)', 'ar_lb': 'Arabic (Lebanon)', 'ar_ly': 'Arabic (Libya)', 'ar_ma': 'Arabic (Morocco)', 'ar_tn': 'Arabic (Tunisia)', 'ast_es': 'Asturian (Spain)', 'az': 'Azerbaijani', 'az_az': 'Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan)', 'az_az.iso88599e': 'Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan)', 'bs': 'Bosnian', 'bs_ba': 'Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina)', 'ca': 'Catalan', 'ca_ad': 'Catalan (Andorra)', 'ca_es': 'Catalan (Spain)', 'ca_es@valencia': 'Catalan (Spain)', 'ca_fr': 'Catalan (France)', 'ca_it': 'Catalan (Italy)', 'da': 'Danish', 'da_dk': 'Danish (Denmark)', 'de': 'German', 'de_at': 'German (Austria)', 'de_be': 'German (Belgium)', 'de_de': 'German (Germany)', 'de_lu': 'German (Luxembourg)', 'el': 'Greek', 'el_cy': 'Greek (Cyprus)', 'el_gr': 'Greek (Greece)', 'el_gr@euro': 'Greek (Greece)', 'en_be': 'English (Belgium)', 'en_dk': 'English (Denmark)', 'es': 'Spanish', 'es_ar': 'Spanish (Argentina)', 'es_bo': 'Spanish (Bolivia)', 'es_cl': 'Spanish (Chile)', 'es_co': 'Spanish (Colombia)', 'es_ec': 'Spanish (Ecuador)', 'es_es': 'Spanish (Spain)', 'es_py': 'Spanish (Paraguay)', 'es_uy': 'Spanish (Uruguay)', 'es_ve': 'Spanish (Venezuela)', 'eu': 'Basque', 'eu_es': 'Basque (Spain)', 'fo': 'Faroese', 'fo_fo': 'Faroese (Faroe Islands)', 'fr_lu': 'French (Luxembourg)', 'fy_nl': 'Western Frisian (Netherlands)', 'ger_de': 'German (Germany)', 'gl': 'Galician', 'gl_es': 'Galician (Spain)', 'hr': 'Croatian', 'hr_hr': 'Croatian (Croatia)', 'hsb_de': 'Upper Sorbian (Germany)', 'id': 'Indonesian', 'id_id': 'Indonesian (Indonesia)', 'in': 'Indonesian (Indonesia)', 'in_id': 'Indonesian (Indonesia)', 'is': 'Icelandic', 'is_is': 'Icelandic (Iceland)', 'it': 'Italian', 'it_it': 'Italian (Italy)', 'kl': 'Kalaallisut', 'kl_gl': 'Kalaallisut (Greenland)', 'km_kh': 'Khmer (Cambodia)', 'lb_lu': 'Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)', 'lo': 'Lao', 'lo_la': 'Lao (Laos)', 'lo_la.cp1133': 'Lao (Laos)', 'lo_la.ibmcp1133': 'Lao (Laos)', 'lo_la.mulelao1': 'Lao (Laos)', 'mk': 'Macedonian', 'mk_mk': 'Macedonian (Macedonia)', 'nl': 'Dutch', 'nl_aw': 'Dutch (Aruba)', 'nl_be': 'Dutch (Belgium)', 'nl_nl': 'Dutch (Netherlands)', 'ps_af': 'Pashto (Afghanistan)', 'pt': 'Portuguese', 'pt_br': 'Portuguese (Brazil)', 'ro': 'Romanian', 'ro_ro': 'Romanian (Romania)', 'rw': 'Kinyarwanda', 'rw_rw': 'Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)', 'sl': 'Slovenian', 'sl_si': 'Slovenian (Slovenia)', 'sr': 'Serbian', 'sr@cyrillic': 'Serbian', 'sr@latn': 'Serbian', 'sr_cs': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_cs.iso88592@latn': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_cs@latn': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_me': 'Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)', 'sr_rs': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_rs@latn': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.cp1251@cyrillic': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.iso88592': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.iso88595': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.iso88595@cyrillic': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.microsoftcp1251@cyrillic': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.utf8': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu.utf8@cyrillic': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'sr_yu@cyrillic': 'Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)', 'tr': 'Turkish', 'tr_cy': 'Turkish (Cyprus)', 'tr_tr': 'Turkish (Turkey)', 'vi': 'Vietnamese', 'vi_vn': 'Vietnamese (Vietnam)', 'vi_vn.tcvn': 'Vietnamese (Vietnam)', 'vi_vn.tcvn5712': 'Vietnamese (Vietnam)', 'vi_vn.viscii': 'Vietnamese (Vietnam)', 'vi_vn.viscii111': 'Vietnamese (Vietnam)', 'wo_sn': 'Wolof (Senegal)'}
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/SurefootedMessyBusinesssoftware)