# Change the type of a numeric string with a space separating the decimal places to int/float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, numeric

I have a pandas column with `str` values. I need to change its type to `int`. The problem is that all values are separated with (`' '`) to differentiate the Ks and the Ms, ex:

```
a = '17 000 000'
int(a)
print(a)
```

output:

```
17000000
```

Comment: `df['col'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)` or `pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.replace(' ', ''))`

Comment: prefect thanks worked out fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to do this by [changing `locale` settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938429/3218693) and applying `locale.atof()`.

*CAUTION*: don't use this if other locale-related logics were present.

Code:

```
import locale
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["17 000 000", "15 000,22"]})

# change locale settings    
locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = " "
locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"] = ","

# apply
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(locale.atof)
```

Result:

```
print(df)
             A
0  17000000.00
1     15000.22
```

Personally I think the `df["A"].str.replace(" ", "").astype(int)` construct mentioned by @Erfan is recommended.