# How to format a number with comma every four digits in Python?

Tags: python, string, localization, format, numbers

I have a number `12345` and I want the result `'1,2345'`. I tried the following code, but failed:

```
>>> n = 12345
>>> f"{n:,}"
'12,345'
```

Comment: I don't believe there are any built-in formatters for that, since that's a really weird requirement.

Comment: It's a weird requirement that is used by at least 2 billion people in the world.

Answer (score 7):

Regex will work for you:

```
import re


def format_number(n):
    return re.sub(r"(\d)(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))", r"\1,", str(n))
```

```
>>> format_number(123)
'123'
>>> format_number(12345)
'1,2345'
>>> format_number(12345678)
'1234,5678'
>>> format_number(123456789)
'1,2345,6789'
```

**Explanation:**

Match:

- `(\d)` Match a digit...
- `(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))` ...that is followed by one or more groups of exactly 4 digits.

Replace:

- `\1,` Replace the matched digit with itself and a `,`

Answer (score 3):

You can break your number into chunks of 10000's using modulus and integer division, then `str.join` using `','` delimiters

```
def commas(n):
    s = []
    while n > 0:
        n, chunk = divmod(s, n)
        s.append(str(chunk))
    return ','.join(reversed(s))

>>> commas(123456789)
'1,2345,6789'
>>> commas(123)
'123'
```

Comment: You could use divmod to do the div and the mod in one hit.

Comment: @wim Good idea, updated

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a locale thing<sup>(*)</sup>. This prints `12,3456,7890` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczRCoIwFMbx@z3FGIQKIyzN7MK36E5kiC4b6DnjbAo9/RpZt93@@X6fffknQlFbCsEsFsnzGYd@1owBb/jpXJSX6lrfcsb2flS4aSIzarWHAWFrRXxZXQ@jU05b0UUqpPhPJsLVGpg@67aUPO@YJQM@/bIH0tJ75XyMU5ocxkRykPznmjutOstCeAM)):

```
import locale

n = 1234567890

locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = ","
locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = [4, 0]
print(locale.format_string('%d', n, grouping=True))
```

That's an I guess hackish way based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938429/16759116). The other answer there talks about using `babel`, maybe that's a clean way to achieve it.

<sup>(*)</sup> Quick googling found [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-grouping-digits-in-large-numbers-based-on-powers-of-10-000-e-g-123-4567-89-still-common-in-China) talking about Chinese grouping four digits, and OP's name seems somewhat Chinese, so...

Comment: This feels like the correct answer. (This grouping is used in China, Japan, Korea, and a few other countries in Asia.)

Answer (score 3):

##### Using [`babel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html):

```
>>> from babel.numbers import format_decimal
>>> format_decimal(1234, format="#,####", locale="en")
'1234'
>>> format_decimal(12345, format="#,####", locale="en")
'1,2345'
>>> format_decimal(1234567890, format="#,####", locale="en")
'12,3456,7890'
```

This format syntax is specified in [UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE (LDML)](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns). Some light bedtime reading there.

##### Using [`stdlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) only (hackish):

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> n = 12345
>>> ",".join(wrap(str(n)[::-1], width=4))[::-1]
'1,2345'
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer, good suggestion!