# Formating a Parsed Number into a float()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing a bank's website to get the exchange rate.

However the format they return is `"61,8000"` and it's a string.

I've tried `float()` but it throws an error.

And the last thing I've tried is:

```
sell = "{:10.6f}".format( e.select_one('.prodazenVal').text.strip() )
buy = "{:10.6f}".format( e.select_one('.kupovenVal').text.strip() )
middle = "{:10.6f}".format( e.select_one('.sredenVal').text.strip() )
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs/fetchExchangeRate.py", line 28, in <module>
    sell = "{:10.4f}".format( e.select_one('.prodazenVal').text.strip() )
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

---

I want to get: `"61.8000"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't know what `e.select_one('.prodazenVal').text.strip()` is. Can you insert the actual string?

Comment: @peer It's `61,8000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python to change to a [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/locale.html) that uses the comma as the decimal separator, such as Russian, like this:

```py
import locale
locale_backup = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, locale='ru_RU')

sell = "{:10.6f}".format(locale.atof(e.select_one('.prodazenVal').text.strip()))
buy = "{:10.6f}".format(locale.atof(e.select_one('.kupovenVal').text.strip()))
middle = "{:10.6f}".format(locale.atof(e.select_one('.sredenVal').text.strip()))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, locale_backup)
```

The `locale.atof` method can be used to convert a localized numeric string to float.

Comment: And then you have to always remember to change the locale back anywhere you use this, if you want to use the actual locale in some other place. This is a really really messy solution.

Comment: @ruohola. I'd argue that this is much less arbitrary than your solution, but the cleanup is indeed undesirable. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50737783/2988730

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda ugly, but will work:

```
def format_to_float(string):
    return "{:10.6f}".format(float(string.strip().replace(",", ".")))


sell = format_to_float(e.select_one('.prodazenVal').text)
buy = format_to_float(e.select_one('.kupovenVal').text)
middle = format_to_float(e.select_one('.sredenVal').text)
```

We first `strip()` all whitespace, then `replace()` the comma with a dot to make `"61,8000"` -> `"61.8000"`, and then call `float()` on it, before `format()`ting it.